# Which is better for a log system ( history ) a MySQL table or a text file on server?

Tags: php, mysql, file, web

I made a database with web interface (PHP) for a store and I made a log system "history page" so every change made on the stock will be saved. I made it with an MySQL table with 5 columns (date / user / action / product / changes), but what if I made a file "log.txt" that change every time a user make an action? Which is better / faster and why?

Comment: what is the RDBMS used on the server? I know you tagged as "mysql", but you don't make a mention of it in the title or the question, only "SQL", which is rather broad.

Comment: it's MySQL sry my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For text files, unless you create a system that ensures that the file is only written to by one thread at a time (like a logging framework would do) you might run into concurrency issues.

A "SQL table" (MS SQL/MySQL/Postgres etc) would be able to handle many concurrent log messages at once. It is however a bit overkill and as your table grows some queries against that table may slow down your database file size will grow too.

Given your scenario (php web app with a history page) SQL is going to be preferable over a text file.

Comment: About your: *"as your table grows some queries against that table may slow down your database file size will grow too"* - Why is that? MySQL etc. db's in general can handle millions of records, no sweat.

Comment: Yeah I just meant you might need to tune some indexes for the queries used. Adding those indexes might impact write performance. Log output could be millions of records in not to long as well depending on usage/verbosity.

Answer (score -1):

Both are essentially the same thing right? Both store the data to a file and read the data from the file.

Generally I would say if you need to find specific data within the file a database is going to make accessing that data easier and faster. If you only need to append to the data and then read, for example, the last 1000 lines, a text file is going to be easier and faster.

I would recommend using a log utility to write the log to a text file, if you decide to go that route. The log utility will deal with concurrency issues.

Comment: Files are a lot of work, especially when it comes to updating. Now, why would working with text files be faster than a database; do you have comparison benchmark tests to back this up with?

Comment: How are files a lot of work? Especially when most languages have a built in log tool that can be configured to save to a file. Do we need benchmarks to figure this out? Reading X lines from a file is going to be as fast or faster than reading X rows from a database. One does more work, simply put.

Comment: have you ever worked with a text type of database before? I'll tell you one thing, I have and ever so thankful I took the initiative to learn how. Edit: text files are a pain in the neck and I know how those feel like also.

Comment: We are not talking about a text database. We are talking about a SQL database or a log file.